# Can I create a Python (3.10) Dictionary with types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary but also define types of key and values. For example, its C# code would be something like :
`Dictionary<string,MyClass> myDict = new Dictionary<string,MyClass>();`
is this possible ? If it is not then can I cast the values or keys later in the code?

Comment: take a look at [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python is a dynamically typed language, this is not possible.
You can, however, add type hints to e.g. the method returning such a dict to inticate to the user what types to expect.

```py
def make_dict() -> dict[str, MyClass]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case a more general answer was/is saught, the whole topic of [Static Typing with Python](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) now has a pretty good introduction. The linked landing page has plenty of follow-up information. I'll try to link to some of the most relevant jump targets; if you have time, just start from the link above.

- **Just give me a cheatsheet!** look at mypy (*the* type linter for Python): [Type hints cheat sheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) from the official mypy documentation.
- **How do I start?** just look at the very next page [Using mypy with an existing codebase](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/existing_code.html) with good guidance for first steps, how to handle the state when full coverage/error-free'ness is still out of reach.

And just to be clear: type annotations do not change Python's dynamic runtime behaviour. They are just for static analysis tools, so that probable bugs can be caught *before* any exceptions at runtime may occur. Clever coding still can trick the checkers and create type-related bugs.